# SQL command to clean job queue in pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.6

I have a Postgres 9.6 installation on a developer pc and a restore seems to have failed. Even after reinstalling (remove Postgres and PgAdmin completely, incl. database and installed new version) the boxes are popping up (even though these tables do not even exist anymore). How to remove these scheduled jobs? Is there an SQL statement to stop these and cleanup the queue? Both jobs are running endless (3000000s+ already).

[image]

Comment: I tried this didn't work :/ . What else did you do? just uninstall, delete folder and reinstall ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file

C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.db

is an sqlite-database.

Open it (e.g. with https://sqlitebrowser.org/) and delete all rows in the process table. Then restart pgAdmin - the boxes should be gone.

Comment: I get an error: no such table: main.user_old

Answer (score 1):

Found solution: This problem is related to the `pgadmin.db`. Just remove the file and the error is gone (but you also have to reenter all passwords etc.). The problem is that this file is not removed when uninstalling postgres/pgadmin. It can be found in

> C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin

Comment: This doesnt make sense, Any new solution for this? I cant be deleting the file each time a restore fail.

Comment: Well, it is a bug and it is Open Source. You could fix it or use command-line for this task instead. At least the above suggestion solves the problem if it occurs.