# Stop restoring backup in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, restore, pgadmin, postgresql-9.6, pgadmin-4

I am currently restoring a database and I tried to restore the database three times. The third time I succeeded but unfortunately it seems that the other two attempts at restoring the database are still running but never finish.

I have these two blue windows on the pgAdmin screen which I can not remove or stop executing. I tried a lot of things, I even uninstalled PostgreSQL two times but the restoring windows appeared again.

I am using Windows 8 and PostgreSQL 9.6.

[image]

Comment: Do you see multiple pgAdmin 4 processes in Task Manager?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No there is just one process for pgAdmin 4 in Task Manager.

Comment: It sounds then as a bug.  I think your best idea is to report it.  Also, have you tried to uninstall pgAdmin 4 itself?  Hopefully it cleans up after itself.

Comment: Yes I uninstalled everything, well I at least tried to. I will report it thank you though.

Comment: I had the same problem and I took the simple way, I delete the server from pgAdmin and then I created it again and thats it, no more infinite back up precesses.

Comment: See this link. it works for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679353/sql-command-to-stop-job-in-pgadmin-4

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and this helped me to solve it:

[SQL command to clean job queue in pgAdmin 4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155727/sql-command-to-clean-job-queue-in-pgadmin-4?rq=1)

I just had to uninstall pgAdmin, delete all the files on C:Program Files directory and in App Data directory, as well.

Comment: Why not only the file the linked answer mentions?

Comment: That's actually a good one. I have started with deleting the installed files so I had it little bit messy afterwards. That's why I did delete actually all the files and started everything from the scratch.

Comment: It can help, to delete just the one file in App Data directory.

Comment: because deleting the file this will remove all the setup of PGAdmin (e.g. stored servers and connections). @PavelReissmann thx for the great tip!

Answer (score 1):

1. Close pgAdmin.
2. Kill the process (pg_dump.exe) from Task Manager window.
3. Open pgAdmin and click on "Click here for details" in the blue-popup-window.
4. Close the details-popup-window opened.

Comment: I had to do an intermediate step between 2 & 3: renaming/moving the file it tries to import. Next time you open PGAdmin 4 the job fails immediately

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete this file C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin database file  but the AppData is a hidden directory , you type  %AppData% in the start in windows , you will directed to Roaming folder .